# DAX to SUM over column with already cumulative in time values, by different category context

Tags: powerbi, dax

this is my data:

[image]

I need a sum of latest cumulative values (column/not measure) depending on project filter context.
Eg. if I use slicer for x,y I need 13 as in rightmost column:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi, your cumulative is a column or it's a  measure ?

Comment: Hi, thanks, it's a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VAR projectLastDates=
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            Values(tbl[proj])
            ,"lastDate",CALCULATE(LASTDATE(tbl[date]))
        )
VAR lastValues=
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            projectLastDates
            ,"lastValue",   VAR lastProjDate=[lastDate] 
                            RETURN 
                                CALCULATE(
                                    SUM(tbl[cum])
                                    ,tbl[date]=lastProjDate
                                )
        )
RETURN SUMX(lastValues,[lastValue])
```